Is building a 3rd party Docker image insecure?
Assuming:

A 3rd party provides a Dockerfile that I do not review
I build the Docker image (docker build or similar) on my infrastructure
the build has a time limit (e.g. max 5 minutes)

Is this insecure for my infrastructure/machine?
If so, why?
For more context, this is like a CI system where I build customer's Docker images on my infrastructure.

Opinion-based questions are discouraged on Stack overflow. IMO, the answer is "yes" because you cannot prove that a given Dockerfile won't damage your infrastructure. I think the time limit is irrelevant. The issue is that a Dockerfile can run arbitrary code on your infrastructure.

@DazWilkin "Is it insecure?" yes/no. Is that opinion-based? I'm looking for facts as to why it would be insecure.

This is not a programming question. Operations types of questions are more appropriate for other sites like serverfault.SE.

"insecure" is not as well-defined as you might think. Is it insecure to be able to access any other non-secured services on your local network? Were any of those services built/configured with the assumption that only "benevolent" code would be able to reach them? Then you'd break that assumption. Is "wasting resources" considered a security risk? (In some situations it certainly is, in other's not so much). How are you ensuring that your docker infrastructure itself doesn't run old un-patched software with known exploits?

You are giving arbitrary code access to write to disk, use memory, use up to 5 minutes of CPU time, access the network, and access the same kernel running everything else on the host. There are various attacks I could think of:

An attacker could potentially use the network access to pivot to other internal resources, or spawn lots of builds to DoS external users.
They could potentially use network access for sending spam.
They could trigger a denial of service on the host by exhausting the resources (filling the disk or using all of the memory).
They could launch a fork bomb to exhaust the kernel of resources and make the host inaccessible/crash.
If an exploit is found in the kernel, container runtime, or build tooling, that exploit could potentially give them access to access the host directly.


Generally speaking and without knowing the tool you're going to use, if you do not review the Dockerfile, it may be insecure.
In fact, a Dockerfile contains a set of instructions that will compose your image and it can include imported libraries and custom software that will reside and execute.
When docker build runs, each layer executes in the context of a container. So the risks are constrained by what access is available to the building container.
So, related secuity issues can be both at internal and external level:

internaly: potentialy, the containers can run any type of attack towards the host machine where it's running since Docker is not a sandbox but runs processes on the host machine, thus, the risks are similar to downloading unknown software from the internet and run on your host
externaly: the malicius software may use your infrastructure and your computation resources (cpu, ram, disk, network) to send maliciuos attacks, or spam messages, towards other hosts in your network

To dig a little bit more into Docker security, it's important to understand how to improve it. With Docker you can try to limit the security risks by restricting what the Docker engine instance can do, for example by:

enabling on the usage of user namespace on the Docker daemon (https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/userns-remap/)
preventing the host from a fork bomb attack, by enabling a maximum number of processes https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/pids.html

Finally, you can prevent Dockerfile harm by:

adopting a widely popular software and tools that, even if you do not check their internals, they are widely spread and use in several contexts and are known to be secure
reviewing many Dockerfile available online, e.g. from Docker Hub, because they indicates the layers that composes the Dockerfile and the public repository connected to the Docker image. So, even if you don not write the Dockerfile, you can see the details of the Docker image.


"it may be insecure." Thanks. Any idea why?

I edited my answer with much more information about the potential security risks of building Docker images.

Yes,
It could have any configuration and install any software inside the container and could be bridged with access various parts of your network and system.
In laymens, docker is just a more efficent take on a virtual machine, it can have anything on it.
Ultimately, don't download and build containers you're unsure of, use trusted sources. It is up to you to review the dockerfile before building it, the docker file will show what is being installed on the image and any configurations that might expose or bridge the network.
If you don't really understand the file itself, disable anything referncing network, ports or host configuration in the dockerfile, spin up the container and using the cli, docker desktop or equivilent tool where you can browse the containers filesystem/poke around inside.
